# How to configure Vue with SCSS

Tags: vue.js, sass-loader

The second I change

```html
<style>
```

to

```html
<style lang="scss">
```

I start getting errors in the terminal:

```
18% building modules 74/80 modules 6 active
...vue-router/src/components/Landing.vue(node:30664)
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:121:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1039:7)
    at getSassOptions (/home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/utils.js:166:37)
    at Object.loader (/home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:43:55)
    at LOADER_EXECUTION (/home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:119:14)
    at runSyncOrAsync (/home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:120:4)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at Object.context.callback (/home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.module.exports (/home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js:21:8)
    at LOADER_EXECUTION (/home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:119:14)
    at runSyncOrAsync (/home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:120:4)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at /home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4
    at /home/dan/working_files/agile/agile-admin-docker/frontend/vue-router/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:70:14
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
created) (node:30664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
`--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
(rejection id: 2) (node:30664) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
non-zero exit code.
```

I believe I have installed the dependencies needed, it appear from the trace that `sass-loader` may be an issue here.

I installed sass using the command

```
npm install -D sass-loader@^10.1.1 node-sass
```

Any tips would be much appreciated, as really not sure what the issue could be at this point.

Landing.vue

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Agile Admin App</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
    h1 {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

I also figured my package.json file would be of use, as it may be a version issue for something like webpack or sass-loader

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My App",
  "author": "email@email.email",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use a scss compiler such as https://github.com/angrymonkeycloud/CloudMate which compile it to css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got to the bottom of this sadly, even with the suggestions above.  Ultimately someone at work suggested copying my custom code out, rebuilding the setup in the cli using vite, then reapplying my work.  This appeared to fix the issue.

Doesn't really explain why it broke, but this was the fix in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Did you followed this tutorial? https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass

You may try

```
npm install -D sass-loader node-sass
```

Then, in your webpack config

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted

      // this will apply to both plain `.scss` files
      // AND `<style lang="scss">` blocks in `.vue` files
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  // plugin omitted
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, so I tried various tutorials like that one, unless I have made a rookie mistake.  I have added those lines to my webpack.base.conf.js file, and can see the three modules listed in package.json.  Sadly I still get the strange error above.

Comment: Maybe try to wipe the `node_modules`, clean the cache and install it again ?

Comment: Gets almost impossible when you add other frameworks like vuetify. The versioning of webpack 4, sass, vue-loader and vuetify is a nightmare

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha.12

Comment: Note: Though Vue.js docs still mention the stated modules, `node-sass` says it is deprecated. The npm name for dart-sass (recommended by node-sass page) is just `sass` https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass

Comment: @akauppi depending on what you're using, you may not be able to upgrade to just using `sass` but it's better indeed.